# input() ограничение до 1025 символов python в vs code

Tags: python, input

После того как поучился вёрстке сайтов на языках HTML, CSS и JavaScript, решил поработать в Python и столкнулся с такой проблемой что в при вводе в терминал он не принимает более 1025 символов. Посмотрел настойки терминал, даже решил переустановить операционную систему (что бы наверняка не было каких либо посторонних файлов кроме python - никакого результата не последовало) не помогло. Работаю в Visual Studio Code
(Кнш можно использовать raw_input(), он можно ли обойтись без этого)

Comment: Это довольно странная идея вводить такую кучу текста через input.

Comment: Дело даже не в этом тут ограничение по всем вводам

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку - используете PowerShell или cmd?

Comment: @Kto вопрос именно в этом. Если вам нужно ввести большое количество данных, лучше использовать файл, а не насиловать консоль.

Comment: Я работаю на MacOs

Comment: Тут даже делл в том что не так же работает sys

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос очень обширный у вас получился, но я попробую объяснить как вы можете контролировать данный процесс.

Первое, вам необходимо указать в какой операционной системе вы работаете. В `Windows` под терминалом могут открываться следующие оболочки:

1. `Command promt` aka `cmd`
2. `PowerShell`
3. И всякие специальности наподобие `GIT bach` или я использую `NRF terminal` и т.д.

В `linux` системах или `macOS` свои оболочки, к примеру `bash`, `-ash`, `sh` и так далее.

Второе, что вы понимаете под термином "терминал". Когда вы через оболочку `VSCode` открываете терминал - это значит, что открывается одна из оболочек, которая указана по умолчанию.
Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В примере на картинке можно увидеть какие "терминалы" доступны у меня и предпоследняя строка дает возможность сконфигурировать по умолчанию. Открою секрет, я использую `CMD`. Это видно из скриншота, пометка `(Default)`.

Следовательно, для того чтобы настроить буфер для хранения команд или отображения количества символов я иду в командную строку <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> -> `cmd` -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Заходите в настройки и управляете.

Написано относительно `Windows 10 pro`

**UPD** Попробовал ваш порядок действий на `macOS`, ничего такого не наблюдается.

Могу посоветовать обнулить переменные среды для терминала в `VSCode`.
Для этого <kbd>F1</kbd> -> Open Default Setting (JSON) -> <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Откроется файл с настройками примерно на 7500 строк. Далее перечислю нужные настройки для `macOS`

```json
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {},
"terminal.integrated.automationShell.osx": null,
"terminal.integrated.macOptionIsMeta": false,
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": null,
```

Данные команды можно вносить в локальную папку `.vscode` -> `settings.json`. Но данный файл содержит комментарии, что может помочь найти необходимую настройку. Так же, например, можно найти настройку на максимальное количество отображаемых строк

```json
// Controls the maximum amount of lines the terminal keeps in its buffer.
    "terminal.integrated.scrollback": 1000,
```

и т.д.

Comment: Я работаю на MacOS
И если вводить(как команду) в сам терминал (VS Code) то там нет ограничений, а если делать это через input() то там есть ограничение 1025 символов

Comment: видео в чём проблема https://youtu.be/gx_FfPilkdo

Comment: Пи этом если работать через cmd будет такое же ограничение

Comment: как я понял это ограничение терминала, т.к даже с sys есть ограничение в 1025 символов

Comment: UPD Тут скорее всего проблема не в самом VS Code а в самом терминале мб
+ не до конца понял как править файл