# Как убрать ограничение в терминале в 1025 символов

Tags: python, консоль, input, sys

Я работаю в Python, но появилось какое то ограничение, что не возможно ввести более 1025 символов в терминале(аля cmd на macOS). Я использовал и input() и sys но ничего не меняется.

Операционная система macOS

Comment: как связана вёрстка сайтов и невозможность ввести более 1025 символов в терминале?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [input() ограничение до 1025 символов python в vs code](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1350608/input-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be-1025-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-python-%d0%b2-vs-code)